# Как называется данный вид авторизации

Tags: delphi, авторизация, get

Здравствуйте, вопрос следующий. Как называется данный вид авторизации?

```
http://admin:parol@192.168.1.1/rebootinfo.cgi
```

Браузер ест данный скрипт, а вот в делфи через Indy ругается и не принимает данную ссылку.
Не могу найти инфу по данному вопросу, так как не знаю название метода авторизации...

Требуется лишь сделать гет запрос на роутер для его перезагрузки. Кому не сложно, можно и код на delphi для авторизации. )

Answer (score 4):

Это [URL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url) авторизация

Comment: Похоже что вы таки правы :)

Answer (score 0):

```
IdHTTP1.Request.Username := 'admin';
IdHTTP1.Request.Password := 'parol';
```